# Grails Maven Resolver not working with 2.3.8

Tags: maven, grails, artifactory, aether

I have a grails 2.3.8 project and an Artifactory server.

The Artifactory server requires authentication.

BuildConfig.groovy contains:

```
grails.project.ivy.authentication = {
    repositories {
        mavenRepo "http://SERVER:8081/artifactory/remote-repos"

    }
    credentials {
        realm = "Artifactory Realm"
        host = "SERVER"
        username = "USER"
        password = "PASSWORD"
    }
}


grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "warn" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

//        mavenLocal()

        mavenRepo id: 'Artifactory', url: "http://SERVER:8081/artifactory/remote-repos"

    }

    dependencies {

        runtime 'com.oracle:ojdbc6:11.2.0.1.0'
        build "commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.4"

        compile 'org.jadira.usertype:usertype.jodatime:1.9'
        compile "net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:2.4.6"
    }

    plugins {
        runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.13"
        runtime ":resources:1.2.7"

        build ":tomcat:7.0.52.1"
        compile ':cache:1.1.5'

        compile ":joda-time:1.4"
    }
}
```

When I run:

```
grails runApp
```

I get:

```
Starting process on MYPC/IPADDRESS
Loading Grails 2.3.8
|Configuring classpath
Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact descriptor for xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Error |
Required Grails build dependencies were not found. This is normally due to internet connectivity issues (such as a misconfigured proxy) or missing repositories in grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy. Please verify your configuration to continue.
```

Looks like the Ivy log config does not apply to maven. How do I turn up the logging? Why are my artifacts not resolving?

Comment: Also we are behind a proxy. Proxy settings are configured via add-proxy on Grails command line. Not sure if this is relevant though as the Artifactory server is also inside the firewall.

Comment: Will the `grails.project.ivy.authentication` settings be read if you've set your `grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven"` (and not Ivy)?

Comment: I've the same problem. Did you find a solution for that?

Comment: Created new question for authentication settings: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23669806/what-is-the-correct-way-to-configure-grails-maven-authentication-to-artifactory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Artifactory checked the "Allow Anonymous Access" option in Admin / Sercurity / General

Still doesn't answer why authentication is not working.

I'll raise a separate question on authentication.
[What is the correct way to configure grails maven authentication to Artifactory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23669806/what-is-the-correct-way-to-configure-grails-maven-authentication-to-artifactory)

Answer (score 1):

A little late on the response, but I ran into this type of issue and traced it to a setting that tells Artifactory to respond with a 404 instead of 401 when someone is requesting an artifact from a repo they can't access.

My guess is that Grails does not preemptively authenticate during dependency resolution, so it never tries to use the supplied credentials in the BuildConfig.groovy after getting the 404.

Try turning off that setting as it fixed the issue for me.

Comment: That didn't work. I get an error - "Resolve error obtaining dependencies"

Comment: FYI: This artifactory setting is under the **Admin** tab -> **Security** -> **General** -> **"Hide Existence of Unauthorized Resources"** checkbox.  

------------

"When marked, Artifactory hides the existence of unauthorized resources by sending a 404 response (not found) to requests for resources that are not accessible by the user. Otherwise, the response implies that the resource exists but is protected - by requesting authentication
for anonymous requests (401) or by denying an authenticated request for unauthorized users."

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
grails.project.ivy.authentication = {
    repositories {
        mavenRepo "http://SERVER:8081/artifactory/remote-repos"

    }
    credentials {
        realm = "Artifactory Realm"
        host = "SERVER"
        username = "USER"
        password = "PASSWORD"
    }
}
```

to

```
credentials {
    realm = "Artifactory Realm"
    host = "SERVER"
    username = "USER"
    password = "PASSWORD"
}
```

The recent change from Ivy to Maven is not always reflected 100% correctly in the docs. You are using `maven` so I don't think the `ivy` setting will work here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following configuration in your BuildConfig.groovy:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven"
grails.project.ivy.authentication = {
    repositories {
        mavenRepo('http://SERVER:8081/artifactory/remote-repos') {
             auth([
                realm: "Artifactory Realm",
                username: 'user',
                password: 'pass'
            ])
        }
    }
}

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    ...
    repositories {
        inherits true
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but same result.

Comment: Found this link. http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Aether-dependencies-not-downloading-td4655575.html
But now extra colons in my dependency config

Comment: Try removing the repository from the "grails.project.dependency.resolution" closure. I have tested this setup and it is working for me.

Comment: Removed the mavenRepo with id Artifactory from the grails.project.dependency.resolution closure. Still get the same result.

Comment: @GregPagendam-Turner Do you have other Maven repositories defined in the BuildConfig? When running Grails, do you see any requests in the Artifactory request.log? if so, is the requesting user: "non_authenticated_user"?

Comment: Yes. seeing requests for non_authenticated_user in Artifactory logs after I added mavenRepo line back in to config.